# What exactly is zero?

Tags: number-theory, set-theory, natural-numbers

I'm learning set theory and the construction of set of natural numbers by Peano's axioms, which says "$0$ is a natural number", and everything starts at $0$.

Then what is $0$?

In set theory, every element in a set is still a set. So I think $0$ is just a set, for example, you can declare it to be $\emptyset$. But I'm not sure if this is right.

Axiom of choice is welcomed.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31826) answer your question? We can get a model of Peano arithmetic with a nice representation as a set where zero is $\varnothing$ by using [the finite Von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers) or the [Zermelo ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Zermelo_ordinals). There are other ways to encode the naturals, but these two are especially nice. Is your question mostly about $0$ itself or more about exactly what kind of thing Peano's axioms give you if we accept them?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I believe this proved my hypothesis, thanks.

Comment: Many people define $\Bbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots,\}$, so everything starts with $1$. But I suppose it is still the same question.